# BC2008 - No input sources specified

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I have downloaded web project source code from github.I am using VS2015 enterprise edition and when build the project it throws below two errors.
The source code is in vb.It always throws error and due to that I could not modify existing source code.

1. BC2008 - No input sources specified
2. BC2011 - BC2011    unable to open response file 'C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp96de1e2bc3d24b21b1987021ee3aa247.rsp'

[image]

Comment: Have you googled those error codes yet?

Comment: Yes I have searched for solutions on google as well on blogs but not found much details for this.

Comment: I have uninstalled and reinstall VS2015 again and it resolved this error.

Comment: As far as BC2008 is concerned, this can't be a question requiring help to debug anything. "No input sources specified" implies that there isn't any source code to begin with. Therefore, the question can't be considered "off-topic", as it's still about a tool used for code development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have uninstalled and reinstall VS2015 and it resolved this error.

Comment: That's odd. BC2008 will normally show up when there is no source code to compile for the project. I don't see how reinstalling VS could possibly solve this.